# Name for a Property of Certain Polylines

Tags: discrete-geometry, terminology

> **Question:**
>
> Is there already a name for polylines in the euclidean plane, that have the property, that no interior of none the triangles, defined by one of the polyline's endpoints and a non-adjacent edge, is not intersected by the polyline?

I am tempted to call that property "*bipolar monotonicity*" if no other name has been coined yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen this named, but you might include either "visibility" or "star" in 
your name, as it is roughly doubly star-shaped. Perhaps *bipolar star*?

---

[image: 2Star]

---

Comment: Good idea to introduce binary solar systems into computational geometry.

Comment: Thinking a bit about your suggestion, I guess, I like "*bipolar star-shaped*" best